# Size of a set. Countable or uncountable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have 2 sets:
$$A=\{f\in \Bbb Q^{\Bbb N}:\exists k \in \Bbb N \;\forall\ n \ge k \;(f(n+1)-f(n)=2)\}$$
$$B=\{f \in \Bbb N^{\Bbb N} : \exists k \in \Bbb N\; \forall n\ge k \;(|f(n+1)-f(n)|=2)\}$$

I know that $\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}=\Bbb Q^{\Bbb N}=\mathfrak c$ and I thought that both $A$ and $B$ are uncountable. But it turned out that $A$ is countable and $B$ is uncountable.

Why?

Comment: For $k \in \mathbb{N}$, let $$A_k = \left\{ f\in \mathbb{Q}^{\mathbb{N}} : \bigl(\forall n \geqslant k\bigr)\bigl(f(n+1) - f(n) = 2\bigr)\right\}.$$ What can you say about $A_k$, and what about the relation between $A$ and the $A_k$?

Comment: Isn't $A_{k}$ a subset of $A$? And I'm not sure but I think that $A_{1}+A_{2}+...=A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference is the absolute value in the definition of set $B$.

Regarding set $A$, at some point the relation $f(n+1)-f(n)=2$ becomes true. That means that given $f(n)$ the value of $f(n+1)$ is completely determined: namely, $f(n)+2$.

Regarding set $B$, at some point the relation $|f(n+1)-f(n)|=2$ becomes true, which is equivalent to $f(n+1)-f(n)=\pm 2$. That means that given $f(n)$ there are *two* possible values of $f(n+1)$: namely, $f(n)+2$ and $f(n)-2$.

For set $A$, you basically get to choose any values of the function for finitely many values of $n$, then the function is set. So this is equivalent to the number of finite sequences of integers, which is countable.

For set $B$, you basically get to choose any values of the function for finitely many values of $n$, then you get to choose two values for the rest of the $n$'s. So this is equivalent to the number of infinite sequences of two values (such as $0$'s and $1$'s), which is uncountable (equinumerous to the number of binary expansions of real numbers between zero and one).

Just to clarify: the difference between $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb N$ in the definitions is irrelevant here.

Comment: To show that $|B|=2^{\aleph_0}$ when considering $f\colon\Bbb{N\to N}$ you need a cleverer version of the argument given in my answer. So the difference is not quite irrelevant, it does simplify things. Note that if $f(n)=0$, then there is no $k\in\Bbb N$ such that $k-0=-2$, so $f(n+1)$ is necessarily $2$.

Comment: But this argument was a bit more clear for me. But thanks for your effort. I greatly appreciate it and I found it useful too.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: You are right, but I meant that at the level of my explanation the difference between $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb N$ is irrelevant; the difference was not the cause of the different cardinalities of $A$ and $B$. The difference becomes significant when fleshing out the details, as you note.

Comment: Rory, the difference between a steak and a protein shake might be irrelevant in terms of nutritional values; but when you don't have teeth eating a steak is much harder. :-)

Answer (score 1):

$f \in A$ is a rational sequence satisfying $f(n+1)=f(n)+2$ for $n\geq k$ where $k\in \mathbb{N}$. So to determine an f, it is enough to fix $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and rationals $f(1),f(2),...f(k)$. Thus we only need to choose finite set of rationals to determine f. (Countable union of countable choices is countable) Hence A is countable.

For $f \in B$, we also need to fix a $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $f(1),f(2),...f(k)$. But $|f(n+1)-f(n)|=2$ implies $f(n+1)=f(n) \pm 2$, thus giving 2 choices for $f(n)$ for each $n>k$. This implies B is bijective to $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ which is uncountable.

Hoping I was able to explain my reasoning clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if $f\in A$, and $k$ is as promised from the condition, then $f$ is fully determined by $f(0),\ldots,f(k)$. Since there are only a countable number of finite sequences of rationals, there can be at most countably many elements of $A$.

On the other hand, if you take any $X\subseteq\Bbb N$, you can encode it into a function in $B$ by defining recursively, $f_X(n+1)=(-1)^{\chi_X(n+1)}2+f_X(n)$, and $f(0)=0$.

Namely, start with $0$ and at each step you add $+2$ if $n+1$ is in $X$, or add $-2$ if $n+1$ is not in $X$. Now show that $X\mapsto f_X$ is a bijection, and conclude the ordeal.